# Add custom relationship data to Django query results

Tags: sql, django, django-queryset

I have two models that contain both a one-to-many, via a foreign key, and a many-to-many relationship.  How do I add the extra data in my relationship to my combined queryset.  The foreign key relationship will have hard-coded extra relationship data whereas the many-to-many will get the extra data from the association table.

The relevant details of the models look like the following:

```
class Player(BaseModel):
    user = models.ForeignKey('User', related_name='players', null=True)
    player_name = models.CharField(max_length=500)

class User(AbstractUser, BaseModel):
    full_name = models.CharField(max_length=64, default='')
    watched_players = models.ManyToManyField('Player', through='Role', related_name='watchers')

class Role(models.Model):
    """
    User <-> Player relation
    """
    ROLE = (
        ('Instructor', 'Instructor'), # user is instructor of the player, has read, update access
        ('Spectator', 'Spectator'),   # user is spectator of the player, has read access to data
    )

    user = models.ForeignKey('User', related_name='roles')
    player = models.ForeignKey('Player', related_name='roles')
    role = models.CharField(max_length=10, choices=ROLE, default='Spectator')
```

I want to return a list of all players associated to a given user along with the associated role.  Note that the role for the foreign key should be returned as "Owner".  In raw SQL, I would do the following (assuming the id of my user is 2):

```
select p.player_name, role from player p join role r on p.id=r.player_id where r.user_id=2
union
select p.player_name, 'Owner' from player p where p.user_id=2;
```

I can get all of the players I want via the following:

```
Player.objects.filter(user=user) | Player.objects.filter(watchers=user)
```

But that doesn't get me the extra "role" value.

Comment: use the role table to get all the required data